# Error Side by side

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

First of all, sorry for the length of this message and for my poor English.

I have a application programmed with Visual C++ 2010 and Windows XP application. If I run the application on the same computer where I have installed the Visual Studio, it works without problems but if I run it from another computer with Windows 7 I get an error.

[image]

And the information on the display of events is:

[image]

And if I run the application on a computer with Windows XP the error is:

[image]

And the event display is:

[image]

I have checked the versions that I have installed on three computers msvcr100.dll file. On the computer with windows xp and Visual Studio installed are:

[image]

On the computer with Windows XP without Visual Studio are:

[image]

And on the computer with Windows 7 are:

[image]

You can see that the three computers have the same version of the file (10.0.40219). I have checked the dependencies with "Dependecy Walker" program but has not found anything. Also I uninstalled and installed the Visual Studio 2010 x86 Redistributable but I still have the error.

Can I get help finding a solution?

Thank you very much.

UPDATE:

I have run the command sxstrace with the following result:

=================
  Begin Activation Context Generation.
  Input Parameter:
    Flags = 0
    ProcessorArchitecture = x86
    CultureFallBacks = en-US;en
    ManifestPath = C:\KMQQ760\KMQQ.exe
    AssemblyDirectory = C:\KMQQ760\
    Application Config File =

---

INFO: Parsing Manifest File C:\KMQQ760\KMQQ.exe.
    INFO: Manifest Definition Identity is   kmqq.exe,processorArchitecture="x86",type="win32",version="5.1.0.0".
    ERROR: Line 1: XML Syntax error.
  ERROR: Activation Context generation failed.
  End Activation Context Generation.

=================
  Begin Activation Context Generation.
  Input Parameter:
    Flags = 0
    ProcessorArchitecture = x86
    CultureFallBacks = en-US;en
    ManifestPath = C:\Windows\system32\sppsvc.exe
    AssemblyDirectory = C:\Windows\system32\
    Application Config File =

---

INFO: Parsing Manifest File C:\Windows\system32\sppsvc.exe.
    INFO: Manifest Definition Identity is   System.Security.SoftwareLicensing.Server,processorArchitecture="x86",type="win32",version="  1.0.0.0".
  INFO: Activation Context generation succeeded.
  End Activation Context Generation.

And the RT_MANIFEST resource of kmqq.exe is:

```
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0"><assemblyIdentity processorArchitecture="x86" version="5.1.0.0" type="win32" name="kmqq.exe"></assemblyIdentity><description>KitchenMaster</description><trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3"><security><requestedPrivileges><requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"></requestedExecutionLevel></requestedPrivileges></security></trustInfo><application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3"><windowsSettings><ms_windowsSettings:dpiAware xmlns:ms_windowsSettings="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</ms_windowsSettings:dpiAware></windowsSettings></application></assembly>
```

I do not find file version msvcr100.dll is conflicting. Can it be that the error is other?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On W7, it says 10.0.40219 is the runtime - not the redist.  You need to get the redist package for 40219 and install it even though the runtime exists.   Chances are you have reinstalled the 30319 redist. That will ensure the registry settings are correct.  Alternatively build as MT instead of MD, then there won't be any runtime dependencies on the MSVCRT DLLs.

Comment: There's something very wrong with the manifest in your program, VS2010 no longer uses the side-by-side cache to store the runtime support DLLs, like msvcr100.dll.  So this error should never occur.  How you managed to mess it up like that is entirely invisible.  In VS, use File + Open + File, open kmqq.exe and have a look-see at the RT_MANIFEST resource.

Comment: Also check your executable's manifest file - look for xxx.exe.embedded.manifest.  Look for <dependentAssembly> followed by <assemblyIdentity>  This will tell you the exact version of MSVCRT it wants.  The other alternative is to copy 10.0.40219 DLL to the same directory as the executable.

Comment: I have run the application sxstrace and have looked the RT_MANIFEST resource of kmqq.exe and not see anything unusual.